# Salesforce field alias

Tags: soql

HI i am newer of sales force

I was fired a quire

```
select Name,(select Cou.firstname,Cou.lastName from contacts Cou)  from Account
```

Which display name of account and it's contact details associate with account...
It also display empty entry in contacts 
so i want `not null` condition in my query....

So i was try following

```
select Name,(select Cou.firstname,Cou.lastName from contacts Cou) coust from Account where coust != null
```

and

```
select Name,(select Cou.firstname,Cou.lastName from contacts Cou)  from Account where (select Cou.firstname,Cou.lastName from contacts Cou) != null
```

but none of them is work....

Please give me some guidance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you do something like this

```
select Name,(select Cou.firstname,Cou.lastName from contacts Cou)  from Account
where id in (select accountid from contact)
```

In other words, limit your initial query to only those accounts which have at least one contact

Comment: Glad to help. And thanks @eyescream for the ninja edit

Comment: It was just a minor typo, no point in posting my own answer for that when the core is right :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that this is possible in SOQL - you don't have the capability to limit the results based on the contents of the subquery.  What you'll need to do is query back all of the account records and then process the results, ignoring those that have zero contacts:

```
List<Account> accs = [SELECT Name,(select Cou.firstname,Cou.lastName from contacts Cou) 
                      from Account];
for (Account acc : accs) 
{
    if (acc.Contacts.size()>0)
    {
       // carry out your processing here - e.g. store in another list
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make a "subquery" in `WHERE` clause as long as it hits different object than the one used in `FROM`. For example this will not compile and has to be rewritten: `SELECT Id, Name
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN (SELECT ParentId FROM Account)`. But Doug's answer is perfectly fine.